# Remove duplicates within a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I remove duplicates within a row for Excel **without** using VBA?

**What i have:**

Row 1: `1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3`

**What i want:**

Row 1: `1 | 2 | 3`

Comment: Is that six comma-separated values in a single cell or six cells with one value each?

Comment: six cells with one value each

Comment: Transpose the row to a column. Use Excel's *Remove Duplicates* on the column, transpose the clean column back over the original row

Comment: how to transpose? Paste special?

Comment: Yes, either Paste Special Transpose, or use an array formula with the `TRANSPOSE` function (the later being harder)

Comment: @brettdj You should post this as an answer :)

Comment: What did you use?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about spaces and you have the six numbers in cells A1:F1, you can do this in cells A2:F2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1) > 1, "", A1)
```

And just drag it across.  For your example, that would result in 1, ,2, ,3, .

Answer (score 0):

```
First, split cells to columns using [Text to columns] in the [DATA] tab
2: transpose data
3: [Remove Duplicates] in the [DATA] tab
4: transpose data
5: concat cells
```